# JSONArray not returning correctly

Tags: java, android, json, getstring

I have this JSON data and am trying to process in in Java.

```
{  
   "status":"ok",
   "data":{  
      "user_count":3,
      "limit":20,
      "page_number":1,
      "users":[  
         {  
        "id":330,
            "name":"jeff",
            "email":"xxx@hotmail.com
         },
            "id":335,
            "name":"joe",
            "email":"xxx@hotmail.com
         }
      ]
    },
}
```

I am able to grab the status but will not grab all the users, which is strange as I have another JSON sample that does work.

Here my is my code:

```
                    results = response.getString("status");
                    if (results.equals("ok")) {
                        JSONArray records = response.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < records.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = records.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONArray users = obj.getJSONArray("users");
                            for (int j = 0; j < users.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject v_obj = users.getJSONObject(j);
                                Log.d("Dracula", v_obj.getString("id"));
                                Log.d("Dracula", v_obj.getString("name"));
                                Log.d("Dracula", v_obj.getString("email"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Is the JSON malformed, or something? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I like using this website to check for JSON validity http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is heavily malformed :) Here's the corrected one.

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "data": {
    "user_count": 3,
    "limit": 20,
    "page_number": 1,
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 330,
        "name": "jeff",
        "email": "xxx@hotmail.com"
      },
      {
        "id": 335,
        "name": "joe",
        "email": "xxx@hotmail.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Errors in your JSON:

1. Double quotes completion missing after emails
2. Extra `,` after details:{} object
3. Second user object is missing a opening `{`

Here's a good [tool](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to check your JSON files. Try copy pasting your JSON in it, and try mine. You will see the difference

> UPDATE
>   Moving on to potential Java Issues:

1. Your `data` is not a array but an object, and yet in Java code you are parsing it as one `JSONArray records = response.getJSONArray("data");`

Also, there is a chance that problem is actually in the web services. Sometimes web-services change the datatype from array [] to object {} when only one result is found. Which is why your code which parses `data` as a array fails for this object.  You should either have your dataservice fixed to return it as array of one object like so `data:[{..}]`  or ad a check in java to see if `data` is an array or Object.

If you do confirm that `data` always comes in as a Object (which makes sense looking at the context of your JSON), then switch the code to not iterate on `data` but to iterate on `data.users` like so:

```
 JSONObject records = response.getJSONObject("data");
 JSONArray users = records.getJSONArray("users");

  for (int j = 0; j < users.length(); j++) {
          JSONObject v_obj = users.getJSONObject(j);
           Log.d("Dracula", v_obj.getString("id"));
           Log.d("Dracula", v_obj.getString("name"));
           Log.d("Dracula", v_obj.getString("email"));
  }
```

Comment: Even with that, it's still not getting the correct result though. Urghh.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below corrected json, the json you have posted is malformed

```
{  
           "status":"ok",
           "data":{  
              "user_count":3,
              "limit":20,
              "page_number":1,
              "users":[  
                 {  
                "id":330,
                    "name":"jeff",
                    "email":"xxx@hotmail.com"
                 },
                 {
                    "id":335,
                    "name":"joe",
                    "email":"xxx@hotmail.com"
                 }
              ]
            }
        }
```

Also in your java code:

```
results = response.getString("status");
                    if (results.equals("ok")) {
                        JSONArray records = response.getJSONObject("data");

                            JSONArray users = records.getJSONArray("users");
                            for (int j = 0; j < users.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject v_obj = users.getJSONObject(j);
                                Log.d("Dracula", v_obj.getString("id"));
                                Log.d("Dracula", v_obj.getString("name"));
                                Log.d("Dracula", v_obj.getString("email"));
                            }

                    }
```